# Double columns in a SQL View

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, sql-view

We have a legacy interface that inserts into table T1 that values `"BODY_TEXT" (varcharmax)`, `"BODY_BIN"(varbinarymax)`. 
It currently inserts just to one of the columns, and leave the other one NULL.
Now we implemented a new interface - table T2 that has only `"BODY"(varbinarymax)` column.

I need to create a view V1 that should replace T1, meaning

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS
SELECT 
T2.UNIQUE_ID AS UNIQUE_ID,
```

etc…

Now I don't know how to treat `T2.BODY` column… I need to do something like
`T2.BODY AS (whatever is not null(BODY_BIN, BODY_TEXT))`. It must also support `varcharmax` vs. varbinarymax.
I tried implementing `COALESCE` meaning  `T2.BODY AS COALESCE(BODY_BIN, BODY_TEXT)` but it doesn't work.
Nor does

```
COALESCE(BODY_BIN, BODY_TEXT) AS BODY
T2.BODY AS BODY
```

Again - In the legacy table we had T1 with two columns - BODY_BIN and BODY_TEXT. The user inserted one value and left the other one null, since body is either binary or textual but not both. The new interface has a table T2 that has only one column, BODY (varbinarymax), and I was asked to delete table T1 and create a view with the same name. Meaning in order to preserve backward comparability they should still be able to perform "insert into T1 values X,Y" (X is DATA_BIN or NULL, and Y is DATA_TEXT or NULL), but the content (taken from either X or Y) should be translated into ONE column in the T2 table - BODY.
I have no idea how to pull this one up.

Can you help me?

Thanks,

Nili

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. COALESCE(<varbinary value>, <varchar value>) should work.

Comment: Yes but please notice the direction is different - usually you "map" table to view, meaning COALESCE(DATA_BIN, DATA_TEXT) AS T.BODY, however I need to map a max value from the view, meaning T2.BODY AS COALESCE(DATA_BIN, DATA_TEXT), or something like that...

Comment: Am I reading this correctly: you want to change the Column name depending on which data type is being returned?

Comment: No Tobias. In the legacy table we had T1 with two columns - BODY_BIN and BODY_TEXT. The user inserted one value and left the other one null, since body is either binary or textual but not both. The new interface has a table T2 that has only one column, BODY (varbinarymax), and I was asked to delete table T1 and create a view with the same name. Meaning in order to preserve backward comparability they should still be able to perform "insert into T1 values X,Y" (X is DATA_BIN or NULL, and Y is DATA_TEXT or NULL), but the content should be translated into one column in the T2 table - BODY.

Answer (score 2):

varbinary to varchar (note the order) will cast implicitly. So this works because ISNULL takes the first datatype

```
ISNULL(varchar, varbinary)
```

COALESCE fails because it takes the highest precedence datatype (which is varbinary). The implicit cast is not allowed. `ISNULL(varbinary, varchar)` would fail too

You need an explicit CAST

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (ID int IDENTITY (1,1), charmax varchar(MAX) NULL, binmax varbinary(MAX) NULL)

INSERT @foo (charmax, binmax) VALUES ('text', NULL)
INSERT @foo (charmax, binmax) VALUES (NULL, 0x303131)
INSERT @foo (charmax, binmax) VALUES ('Moretext', NULL)
INSERT @foo (charmax, binmax) VALUES (NULL, 0x414243454647)

SELECT ISNULL(binmax, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), charmax))
FROM @foo
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(binmax, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), charmax))
FROM @foo
```

Edit: I understand the question now... maybe

```
DECLARE @foo2 TABLE (ID int IDENTITY (1,1), BODY varbinary(MAX) NULL)

INSERT @foo2 (BODY) VALUES (CAST('text' AS varbinary(MAX)))
INSERT @foo2 (BODY) VALUES (0x303132)
INSERT @foo2 (BODY) VALUES (CAST('Moretext' AS varbinary(MAX)))
INSERT @foo2 (BODY) VALUES (0x414243454647)
SELECT
    BODY AS BODY_BIN,
    CAST(BODY AS varchar(MAX)) AS BOY_TEXT
FROM
    @foo2
```

Edit2: something like this (*not* tested) to maintain the same write interface. Normally, I'd only maintain a read interface hence the confusion...

```
CREATE VIEW OldFoo
AS
SELECT
    ID,
    BODY AS BODY_BIN,
    CAST(BODY AS varchar(MAX)) AS BOY_TEXT
FROM
    newFoo
GO
CREATE TRIGGER ON OldFoo INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT newFoo (BODY)
SELECT ISNULL(binmax, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), charmax))
FROM INSERTED
GO
```

Comment: I still don't know if a simple cast would work, I'm still one step behind since I don't know how to bind one "physical" column from table T2 to non-null-value-out-of-two-columns from V1...

Comment: @Nili: I have given you proof it *does* work in my script above

Comment: @gbn, still not exactly what I was aiming to.. I used to have an old table - DECLARE @foo TABLE (ID int IDENTITY (1,1), BODY_BIN varbinary(MAX) NULL, BODY_TEXT varchar(max)), and now I got a new table - foo2 - exactly like you presented it. Now the requirement from me is to drop table foo, and instead create a view called foo. It should support old users, meaning support insertion of DATA_BIN AND DATA_TEXT, but "behind the scene" copy JUST ONE VALUE to the brand new table foo2... Is this a better explaination?

Comment: @Nili - If you want to use the view to `INSERT` new data then you need to have two different fields, one for each data type.  The alternative is to have a function that does some logic to determine data type but that borders on a ridiculous level of complication to cram this new method into an old framework.

Comment: @Nili: so users will still try to write to "foo"?

Comment: Yes exactly! And new user will start writing to foo2! That's exactly why I need a view (to replace foo), and whenever users write it it, I need to actually plant the results in the real table foo2 :)  Now the problem is that the view should have two columns, both are mapped to one column in the real table foo2... and of course only the non-null value really matters...

Comment: @Nili: You'd need an INSTEAD OF trigger to intercept the INSERT on the view. It would be an INSERT based on my first example code. And updated again.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a bad design.  Joining on a `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` field is a bad idea since they can't be indexed.  Prepare for table scans!

You have inconsistent data types in the same column, which is a problem.

Try:

`CAST((COALESCE(BODY_BIN, BODY_TEXT)) as varchar(max))`

Comment: But I need to map T2 value into the non-null value, meaning I need something like: T2.Body AS CAST((COALESCE(BODY_BIN, BODY_TEXT)) as varchar(max)), but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Nili: `COALESCE(CAST(BODY_BIN AS varchar(max)), BODY_TEXT))`?